# I need cordova plugin that can read and delete SMS, above Android 4.4+ restrictions

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I need cordova plugin that can read and delete SMS, played around with https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms/tree/master/docs

but now restricted, can't delete and make my app default messaging app.

I installed

https://github.com/rampicos/Cordova-SMS-Plugin

along with the above plugin, with the hope that delete would work, despite making my app default messaging app, can't still delete messages  Please, how can i make it work?

Answer (score 1):

The author of this plugin https://github.com/rampicos/Cordova-SMS-Plugin gave me a clue;

You have to push the SMS to your local storage like SQLite for the future use. Nature of SMS is to broadcasted, so the app has to store it to the local DB and all SMS apps usually do that.